# Ballerina - error when running mock tests

Tags: ballerina

**UPDATED**

Hi I am writing a test function in ballerina as follows (in the package notifications).

```
import ballerina/test;
import ballerina/io;

@test:Mock {
    packageName: "notifications",
    functionName: "getMissingIds"
}
function mockGetMissingCount() returns (int) {
    int count = 3;

    return count;
}

@test:Config
function testAssertArrayEquals() {
    int answer = 0;
    string[] expectedResult = 3;
    string[] actualResult = getMissingCount();
    io:println("Function mocking test");
    test:assertEquals(actualResult, expectedResult, msg = "function mocking failed");
}
```

I have the actual function getMissingCount in another file in  the same package as notificationtest.bal file. However when I run the tests by executing

```
ballerina test notifications
```

the actual getMissingCount function is getting called instead of the mock function. Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens? What would be the workaround.

Comment: Can you check if `getMissingCount` function is public ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this - https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/testerina-function-mocks.html. Your mock function is missing the annotation `@test:Mock`. Also you need to state the package name in the `@test:Mock` annotation.

```
// Mock 'getMissingIds' function of 'notifications' package.
@test:Mock {
    packageName: "notifications",
    functionName: "getMissingIds"
}
function mockGetMissingCount() returns (int) {
    int count = 3;
    return count;
}

@test:Config
function testAssertArrayEquals() {
    int answer = 0;
    string[] expectedResult = 3;
    string[] actualResult = getMissingCount();
    io:println("Function mocking test");
    test:assertEquals(actualResult, expectedResult, msg = "function mocking failed");
}
```

I didnt run the above. But please try.

Comment: I changed the mock function and included test:Mock (updated in the question). But still the actual function is getting called.

Comment: Seems theres an issue in mocking function when in packages. Created an issue to track it - https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/10673

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is when you are running a test that depends on some enclosing package level functions, then you have to run the tests at package level.

For example in the above case, if your package name is `foo` and within that you have all the ballerina source files which also has test cases as the above example, then you have to run the test as `ballerina test foo` which would execute the tests that are found in the package `foo`.

Using `ballerina test <bal-file>` will consider the bal-file as a single entity and it will not know about your enclosing packages/project. So in that case, you may have to have all the functions in the same bal file to get it work.

Comment: Yes, I had to include the tests inside a "tests" folder which I included inside the package which contained the functions I need to test. Then it worked.

Comment: @Krishanthan : when I run the test, the actual getMissingIds function is getting called instead of mock function. Do you know how to call the mock function?